# My redux reducers all look the same. Am I doing it wrong?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm building a quite simple app using Redux and my reducers all look alike. It works, technically, but that's a lot of code duplication.

```
// The employees reducer
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EMPLOYEES_REQUEST:
      return [ ...state, { isFetching: true } ]
    case EMPLOYEES_SUCCESS:
      // DEBUG
      console.log('Dispatching employees');
      console.log(action.response);
      // END DEBUG

      // Return employees directly in the employees state
      return { ...state, list: JSON.parse(action.response) };
    case EMPLOYEES_FAILURE:
      return [ ...state, { isFetching: false } ]
    default:
      return state
    }
}
```

And

```
// The services reducer
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SERVICES_REQUEST:
      return [ ...state, { isFetching: true } ]
    case SERVICES_SUCCESS:
      // DEBUG
      console.log('Dispatching services');
      console.log(action.response);
      // END DEBUG

      // Return services directly in the services state
      return { ...state, list: JSON.parse(action.response) };
    case SERVICES_FAILURE:
      return [ ...state, { isFetching: false } ]
    default:
      return state
    }
}
```

Is there something I can to to use a generic reducer with different actions?

Thanks!

Comment: Just my $0.02, You shouldn't use really use the same key, for instance when you call `SERVICE_SUCCESS` and `EMPLOYEES_SUCCESS` you're using the key `list` again. There's no way to differentiate an Employee list and a Service list. You should favour `employeeList` and `serviceList` IMO. Same with `isFetching` - what are you fetching? It isn't really clear. `isFetchingEmployee` and `isFetchingService` helps alleviate any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducer is just a function. You could always use a higher order function to make it.

```
const makeListReducer = (initial, prefix) => (state = initial, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case `${prefix}_REQUEST`: return {...state, isFetching: true}
    case `${prefix}_SUCCESS`: return {...state, isFetching: false, list: JSON.parse(action.response)}
    case `${prefix}_FAILURE`: return {...state, isFetching: false, /*etc*/}
  }

  return state
}

// The employees reducer
export default makeListReducer(initialState, 'EMPLOYEES')
```